# TFS - Is it possible to link a shelve to a work item? Automatically? (And more)

Tags: tfs, automation, workitem, shelve

Hmm I think the question itself is pretty straight-forward...

In Team Foundation 2010, is it possible to link a shelveset to a work item in some way ?

If so, is it possible to automatically create this link when the developer shelves and associates with a corresponding work item ?

We're working with alot of shelves, it may get messy after a while, so querying our pending work items and knowing the shelveset related to the task at hand would quicken things up.

Is it possible to change a work item state everytime I shelve my work and associate a work item?

And at last but not least, would it be possible to query all work items linked to shelves ? (Assuming we can link them)

Thanks in advance!

~

Comment: It is not possible to link those together. Why do you have so many shelvesets?

Comment: Our ongoing bug fixes and small tasks are all organized in shelvesets instead of a new branch. Then we merge the tasks as needed and delete the shelveset (when its changes are commited into the branch). We're currently only using new branches for long projects and such.